Structure and punctuation of sentence with two clauses joined by "and" where the first ends with a plural noun phrase using "and"
I saw this sentence while looking for train schedules:

The fare per zone is $1.50 for adults (ages 19-64), youth (ages 0-18) and seniors (ages 65+) travel fare-free with no ticket needed.

If the sentence is simply left in the form it's in then I think that the comma between the youth and the adult phrases should be replaced by "and", and a comma should be placed before "and seniors":

The fare per zone is $1.50 for adults (ages 19-64) and youth (ages 0-18), and seniors (ages 65+) travel fare-free with no ticket needed.

Is what I think correct? Using "and" twice in close proximity sounds odd as well as somewhat confusing to me, though adding the comma between the clauses almost demands a pause, something that doesn't feel needed when placing a comma between two independent clauses, and which often leaves me wondering whether the comma is needed or not, such as:

Dad went upstairs to get some work done for tomorrow, and mom stayed down here to watch her favorite show.

The comma doesn't feel necessary and I often don't put one in unless I'm proofing my writing.
But I've gone off on a tangent, it seems. For the original quotation, the problem is made clearer if some of the extra details are removed and the sentence is simplified, like this:

The fare is $1.50 for adults and youth, and seniors travel fare-free with no ticket needed.

Actually, in this case, I'd probably use two sentences or replace the "and" between the two independent clauses with a semicolon:

The fare is $1.50 for adults and youth. Seniors travel fare-free with no ticket needed.

or

The fare is $1.50 for adults and youth; seniors travel fare-free with no ticket needed.

Is either or both of those correct? What would be the preferred form?
(Yes, I know that American English (at least the MLA) would place the comma before the closing quotation mark, but I often use quotation marks when I'm writing about an exact piece of text, and it seems to more accurately be clearer if the text within the quotation marks is literally the text I am speaking about. And yes, I do think it looks "nicer" if the comma comes first. I like seeing and reading well formatted writing, but, especially since I'm often trying to help someone with a problem regarding a computer language, I now lean towards clarity in this situation.

I think that it should be "youth and seniors travel fare-free". I can't imagine a transport organisation allowing seniors to travel free and while also charging a child an adult fare.

I found it a garden-path sentence; I read it as '$1.50 for adults, youth and seniors'.

<< The fare per zone is $1.50 for adults (ages 19-64); youths (ages 0-18) and seniors (ages 65+) travel fare-free with no ticket needed. >.or << The fare per zone is $1.50 for adults (ages 19-64), and youths (ages 0-18) & seniors (ages 65+) travel fare-free with no ticket needed. >> Note the count usage ('youths') to parallel 'adults' and 'seniors'. But covered before in different threads (I'll CV using one): ...

This question is similar to: Is it ok to combine two independent clauses into just one sentence?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. The disambiguation using 'and' + '&' is covered elsewhere.

See B Szonye's answer here for the 'super-' and 'ordinary-and' usage, 'and' and '&'. Compare the 'semicolon as super-comma' device (but with the and's, the ampersand is the less-super, word-pair-relating variant).

The original is muddy, but there is no "and" before youth. Adults and youth do not pay the same.

@Killing Time - I was aware that seniors ride free, and as that was the info I was verifying, I misread the sentence without thinking about youths also being free. Kate Bunting found it a garden-path sentence (adults, youths and seniors was punctuated as a list of items), and when I recall that when I first read it (as a list), I knew that something was wrong when I came to the word "travel." In my attempt to find a clear way to write it, I completely changed its meaning. The whole problem was due to incorrect punctuation, and I chose the wrong way to interpret it.

@Edwin Ashworth - Yes, the question is a duplicate resulting from my misinterpretation of sentence's meaning. But as the title says, the question is about punctuating "and"s and not about punctuating two independent clauses and is really a duplicate of the B Szonye answer you provided. Of course, using the correct interpretation, my title no longer truly fits, though Szonye's answer did answer the question I was posing. (Actually, the paired down example I used makes it clear that I was thinking youths was grouped with adults, but I'll admit that it's still a duplicate.

That's pared down, Zhora.
